# How to use Tag for compare value from database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i want to learn c#.net ., please help me to fix the code ,The quetion is => ., how to use property Tag for compare a value from database???
 i use microsoft visual studio 2010

this project goal to make a Matching game picture

this is code from UI

```
<StackPanel Height="117" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,23,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Tap="stackpanel_Tap_1">
            <Image Source="{Binding SOAL }" Name="Gambar1" Tag="{Binding ID_GAME}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

this is from class

This class i want to make prosedure(void) event click, in this void if i click a stackpanel i will get a ID_GAME, and then i click another stackpanel to compare the ID_GAME, if ID_GAME is match, it will be continue the game.

```
private void stackpanel_Tap_1(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel firstklk = null;
        StackPanel scndklk = null;            
        StackPanel Stn = (StackPanel)sender;            
        if (Stn != null)
        {          
            if (firstklk == null)
            {
                Stn.Tag = this.Tag;
                firstklk.Tag = Stn.Tag;                  
                return;                      
            }
            scndklk.Tag= Stn.Tag;                
            if (firstklk.DataContext == scndklk.DataContext)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("MATCH");
            }           

        }          
            else
           {
                MessageBox.Show(" Not Match ");
           }         

    }
```

if you have another way, you can tell me the code? thanks for help me

Comment: Are you using the MVVM design pattern? If not, you should look into it. Would make this task much easier (and cleaner).

Comment: Yes, i use MVVM design pattern, i just difficult to use tag for compare two ID_picture, can you help me?

Comment: I just want to ask how to get value from localhost in button if i click the button.  please help me master  :)

Answer (score 0):

AS @KillQuotes wrote you need to implement MVVM pattern here. If you are new in the environment is a good advice to read [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153(v=vs.105).aspx) carefully, then you can build your application. Just for reference, you can watch [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Practical-MVVM-For-Windows-Phone). ;)